# JPA (Hibernate) Map multiple entities to one common table (entity)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm having situation where I have multiple entities (Users, Products, Categories) where each of have one or more Images. I want to use only one Image table to persist the info about the images.

I like to achieve something like this with JPA (Hibernate):

```
id  foreign_key     image_type       file_path
1   1               PROFILE_USER     /file/….
2   2               PROFILE_USER     /file/….
3   3               CATEGORY_IMAGE   /file/….
4   4               CATEGORY_IMAGE   /file/….
5   1               PRODUCT_IMAGE    /file/….
```

Where foreign_key is the primary id key for the different entity types ( Users, Categories, Products etc..)
The combination of foreign_key and image_type indicates for the specific entity (
PROFILE_USERS(Users), PRODUCT_IMAGE(Products), CATEGORY_IMAGE(Category) etc..

I want to do this because, it it not cool to have separate image table for the different cases ( Users - > users_images, Products -> product_images, Category -> category_images)

Comment: Why is it not "cool"? At the end of the day, it should not interest you how the data is structured in the DB. You are using Hibernate to make your life easier and you should also use an `Image` superclass which all the other image types inherit from.

Comment: Because for me it is not the most correct way. All images should be on one image table, because in the end, they are images and there is no reason to persist them in different tables... It scales more easyily if I want to add more types..

Comment: What is the point of having both the FK and image_type define the entity class? What you propose is trivial - JPA single table inheritance has many tutorials describing it in detail - but the addition of the FK isn't, and doesn't seem to make sense. You'd need to explain more why a PROFILE_USER would have a different FK value (1 or 2) and what it means to the class, and why it would reference the same FK value as a PRODUCT_IMAGE. Maybe just have a single 'image' entity with these set as properties instead if that FK is really somehow involved. Or separate entities based on image type.

Comment: @Chris I just wanted no to have join table between Products -> products_images -> images.. The JoinTable wil contain only id of the product_id and images_id. I wanted to have one 'global' column which will contain the id's of the different products and with combination of the 'DiscriminatorColumn' to have unique Entity record in Image table :)

Comment: It is still hard to follow, as your original table did not look like not a ManyToMany table or specify the relationship you need between your java entities.. Having User->Image, Product->Image, Category->image via a Many to many is the easiest and usually the best way to do it. If you want UserImage->User and ProductImage->Product, this is a oneToOne or ManyToOne. Again, easy if you create an Image to capture the basics, then have each subclass define a OneToOne or ManyToOne relationship to their respective reference class. check out JPA single table inheritance examples

Comment: @Chris I'll be happy to see your opinion for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I was not able to explain it correctly. I managed to do it as I wanted with @Where annotation on each ProductImage, UserImage etc..
Let me explain it.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Product {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;


  @OrderBy("id")
  @JoinColumn(name = "image_type_id")
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = ProductImage.class)
  private Set<ProductImage> images = new LinkedHashSet<>();


}
```

--

```
@Table(name = "images")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="image_type",
    discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Image {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "original_file_name")
  private String originalFileName;

  @Column(name = "file_name")
  private String fileName;

  @Column(name = "file_path")
  private String filePath;

  @Column(name = "file_size")
  private Long fileSize;

  @Column(name = "thumbnail_path")
  private String thumbnailPath;

}
```

--

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("PRODUCT_IMAGE")
@Where(clause = "image_type = \"PRODUCT_IMAGE\"")
public class ProductImage extends Image {


}
```

Now we have one Image table which is distinguished by each implementation (ProductImages, UserImages etc) only by  DiscriminatorColumn and image_type_id combination of each defines one specific instance from Product ( and his ProductImages).
When the products and his images are query, my select statement is like this - "where ( images0_.image_type = "PRODUCT_IMAGE") and images0_.image_type_id=? order by images0_.id"

There is no need of JoinTable which should contain the relation for image id and product id, in order to distinguishes the images for specific product instance.

@Chris does this make sense for you? Can you find some Pros and Cons for this approach ?

Comment: Ah I love this! I've been wanting to do something similar for a while but never got to it. I can see this as a problem down the line if say one image needs to be connected to multiple other entities from the same type (many to many), but if this would never be the case it is a really neat solution that makes your DB looking neat and ordered without creating too much join tables.